# git: more efficient way to do this

Tags: git, workflow, git-svn

This is my normal workflow with git-svn:

1. create a branch for an issue
2. commit after doing some work on branch
3. checkout master
4. svn rebase
5. checkout branch
6. rebase master
7. checkout master
8. merge branch
9. dcommit

My goal here is to keep my history in a straight line, and also trying to minimize the headache of merges.

Is there a way to do this with less steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do your rebase in the middle, and certainly no need to swap to the master branch to do so. My workflow achieves the same and is thus:

1. Create a branch for an issue: `git checkout -b issue remotes/trunk` (that `remotes/trunk` can be omitted if I'm already on the branch I'm interested in).
2. Do some work, and commit it.
3. Push it straight to the Subversion repository: `git svn dcommit`. This will only fail if files you've edited have been changed. If they have, you'll get an error, so do a `git svn rebase` then try your `git svn dcommit` again.

   Note there's no need to merge this into your master branch first.
4. Checkout the master branch: `git checkout master`.
5. Rebase the master branch: `git svn rebase`.

   Optionally, delete the issue branch; the master and issue branches should now be identical, as `git svn dcommit` does a `git svn rebase` immediately afterwards.

You can do your `git svn` commands from any branch; the system will work out where to commit to or rebase from based on the parent Subversion branch. If you want to check what Subversion branch it's interested in, run `git svn dcommit --dry-run`

In particular, there's nothing particularly special about the master branch. Indeed, I frequently ignore it and skip steps 4–5 above. I'll just swap from one issue branch to another and never bother bringing the master branch up to the Subversion tip.

Comment: are you saying if I clone from trunk, create a local branch, do work and commit, i can rebase from the local branch to the trunk?  I would still need to rebase the master wouldn't I?

Comment: I think the scenario you're describing is where someone has committed changes to the remote Subversion trunk, and you've made commits to your local "issue" branch, and you want to take the remote changes. If you have your "issue" branch checked out (ie `git branch` lists the "issue" branch with a star next to it) then yes, `git svn rebase` will update to have your commit on top of the tip of the Subversion trunk. No need to touch the "master" branch at all.

Comment: essentially right.  My only concern would be if I were working multiple issues at once, all coming from master.  I suppose I could svn rebase individually, and trust that when I merge master will be up to date--i.e. merging a branch that was rebased to master will result in an up to date master -- is that correct?

Comment: There's very little that's special about the master branch for `git-svn` workflows. I personally never touch the master branch. I'll use `git checkout -b newbranchname remotes/trunk` to start a new issue branch, `git svn rebase` when I want to pull changes from the remote trunk into my local branch, and `git svn dcommit` to push changes from the local branch to the remote trunk. There's actually no need to keep the local master branch up-to-date at all.

Comment: thanx for the details -- appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 things at odds here. To keep your history in a single straight line, you need to rebase. However, rebasing implies that you have to re-apply changes on top of a different code base. This can set off a chain of conflict resolutions that you may need to do *for every single commit you are rebasing*.

The only thing I can add to help you is that if you have rebased, you know you will have a fast-forward merge. In this case, you do not need to checkout that branch to move it forward. So to update a reference, you can:

```
git push . my-branch:master
```

This will update master to point to where my-branch is pointing to and will only work if it's fast-forwardable. Unfortunately it's not going to help you here as you require to be on the branches to do the actions you need.

Back to the question of your workflow, you will have more problems with conflicts than you would if you simply merge.

Comment: in this workflow, steps 3-4 should never have a merge problem since my master hasn't changed.  right?  so there might be a merge on 6, but there would by merge on 8.  If I just merged, there is the possibility of a conflict -- i guess what I am saying is there should be at most one conflict

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) instead of git-svn.

SubGit is a server-side solution. It enables Git access to your Subversion repositories as well as Subversion access to Git repositories. One has to install SubGit into Subversion repository, i.e. basically add necessary hooks that does conversion on every push and commit:

```
$ subgit configure $SVN_REPOS
$ # Adjust $SVN_REPOS/conf/subgit.conf 
$ #     to specify your branches and tags
$ # Adjust $SVN_REPOS/conf/authors.txt 
$ #     to introduce svn author names to their git counterparts
$ subgit install $SVN_REPOS
```

After that one has a Git repository at $SVN_REPOS/.git which is continuously synchronized with its Subversion counterpart. When remote access is configured for this Git repository (e.g. via [git-http-backend](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-http-backend.html)), one can use any Git workflow and any Git client with existing Subversion repository.

For your case it would look like this:

```
$ git checkout -b foo
$ git commit
$ git checkout master
$ git merge foo or git rebase foo
$ git push
```

Some more details:

- SubGit is much more superior than git-svn in terms of merge-tracking, end-of-line, mime-type support, etc;
- SubGit is a commercial tool with some free options;
- I'm one of SubGit developers.